# Algorithm for efficient portfolio optimization

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, finance, portfolio

I'm trying to find the best allocation for a portfolio based on backtesting data. As a general rule, I've divided stocks into large caps and small/mid caps and growth/value and want no more than 80% of my portfolio in large caps or 70% of my portfolio in value. I need an algorithm that will be flexible enough to use for more than two stocks. So far, what I have is (including a random class called Ticker):

```
randomBoolean=True
listOfTickers=[]
listOfLargeCaps=[]
listOfSmallMidCaps=[]
largeCapAllocation=0
listOfValue=[]
listOfGrowthBlend=[]
valueAllocation=0
while randomBoolean:
    tickerName=input("What is the name of the ticker?")
    tickerCap=input("What is the cap of the ticker?")
    tickerAllocation=int(input("Around how much do you want to allocate in this ticker?"))
    tickerValue=input("Is this ticker a Value, Growth, or Blend stock?")
    tickerName=Ticker(tickerCap,tickerValue,tickerAllocation,tickerName)
    listOfTickers.append(tickerName)
    closer=input("Type DONE if you are finished. Type ENTER to continue entering tickers")
    if closer=="DONE":
        randomBoolean=False

for ticker in listOfTickers:
    if ticker.cap==("Large" or "large"):
        listOfLargeCaps.append(ticker)
    else:
        listOfSmallMidCaps.append(ticker)
    if ticker.value==("Value" or "value"):
        listOfValue.append(ticker)
    else:
        listOfGrowthBlend.append(ticker)
for largeCap in listOfLargeCaps:
    largeCapAllocation +=largeCap.allocation

if largeCapAllocation>80:
    #run a function that will readjust ticker stuff and decrease allocation to large cap stocks
    

for value in listOfValue:
    valueAllocation+=value.allocation

if valueAllocation>70:
    #run a function that will readjust ticker stuff and decrease allocation to value stocks
```

The "function" I have so far just iterates through -5 to 6 in a sort of

```
for i in range (-5,6):
    ticker1AllocationPercent + i
    ticker2AllocationPercent - i
    #update the bestBalance if the new allocation is better
```

How would I modify this algorithm to work for 3, 4, 5, etc. stocks, and how would I go about changing the allocations for the large/small-mid cap stocks and such?

Comment: Often a Quadratic Programming solver is used for that. You don't want to implement that. Just use an existing one. And read a book on portfolio optimization.

Comment: If you want help with *programming* (which is what we do here) it often helps if you don't assume that everyone is familiar with the terms and concepts of your problem domain (investments and portfolios?).  That way you can present is a programming question rather than a problem domain question.  If it really is a problem-domain question, then those are best asked at a site for the specific problem domain.  If it is *both*, then it may help to see if you can separate your question(s) into those different parts.  (Also, many domain-specific sites have programmers specializing in that domain).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the above answer, typically Quadratic solver is used in such problems. You can use Quadratic solver available in Pyportfolio. See [this link](https://pyportfolioopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MeanVariance.html?highlight=quadratic#pypfopt.objective_functions.quadratic_utility) for more details.